# Spark transformation that withdraws objects from a ListBuffer in a RDD[ListBuffer] and creates new entries in the RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have an RDD which is `RDD[ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]]`. For simplicity we can just call it `RDD[X]`, where `X` is a list of some variables. `X` is a list of `obj` objects, `X[obj]`.

The idea is that I want a function which takes `RDD[X]` as input and outputs a new `RDD[X]`, a transformation. This transformation will create new `X` lists by taking out `obj` from one `X` and creating a new one, and like "appending" it to the RDD.

I haven't found anything in Spark that supports this directly. Right now the only solution I can think of is by performing `collect()` and managing most of this at the driver but this is obviously not good. Any ideas?

Basically something like this:

```
val data = RDD[ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]]
// some transformation that calls some function
// what will happen is some (Array[String], Long) will be moved into an entirely new ListBuffer in outData while some may be completely removed
val outData = RDD[ListBuffer[(Array[String], Long)]]
```

Lets say if we have a starting RDD that contains one ListBuffer of 7 elements:

> Element1 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element2 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element3 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element4 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element5 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element6 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element7 (in ListBuffer1)

And after the transformation the RDD will have the following contents:

> Element1 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element2 (in ListBuffer1)
>
> Element4 (in ListBuffer2)
>
> Element5 (in ListBuffer2)
>
> Element6 (in ListBuffer2)

Some elements have been moved to a new ListBuffer in the RDD while two elements were completely removed.

I am using Spark 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do transformation on each `ListBuffer` to collection of `ListBuffer` let say `List` of `ListBuffer` then do `flatMap` on RDD.

Below is the dummy POC.

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(List(1,2,3,4), List(11,22,76,44)))
val flattenRdd = rdd.map(s => List(s.filter(_%2 == 1), s.filter(_%2 == 0)))
    .flatMap(s => s)
flattenRdd.collect().foreach(s => println(s.mkString(",")))

1,3
2,4
11
22,76,44
```

Comment: What if I don't know how many Lists there are in the Seq? In my case, this can very between 1 and thousands.

Comment: Lets say if I run rdd.map(s => func(s)).flatMap(s => s) and function splits one s into multiple s. Will that work? For example if func takes one Seq as input and returns a List of 3 Seq's. (The one Seq was splitted into 3)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much, got it working with my real code!